# Reserva Semanal

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de agendamento e já está quase tudo certo porem surgiu uma dúvida eu preciso criar uma opção para agendamento semanal caso o usuário clicasse em agendamento semanal ele agendasse toda a semana no horário escolhido pelo cliente mais ou menos assim:

```
Cliente Jose Horário 13:00 as 14:00 Agendamento semanal ? sim !
```

Então o sistema agendaria para ele:

```
segunda das 13:00 as 14:00 terça das 13:00 as 14:00 quarta das 13:00 as 14:00 quinta das 13:00 as 14:00 sexta das 13:00 as 14:00
```

Não precisem mostrar o código apenas me auxiliar na lógica acho que já é o suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Trabalhei com uma agenda a poucos dias, a lógica é a seguinte:

Dê a opção de data de início e data de fim.

Faça uma consulta no banco buscando os agendamentos:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM agendamento WHERE data_inicio >= CURDATE();
```

Faça uma estrutura que monte essas ocorrências semanais:

```
$eventos = Array();
foreach ($res as $row){

    if ($row['semanal'] == 1){

        $data_inicio = $row['data_inicio'];
        $data_fim = $row['data_fim'];

        // Calcule o intervalo das datas em dias
        $intervalo == IntervaloDias($data_inicio, $data_fim);

        // Data do evento (atual)
        $data = $data_inicio;
        for($i = 0; $i < $intervalo; $i++){
            $eventos[] = Array(
                'data_inicio' => $data,
                'data_fim' => $data,
                'hora_inicio' => $row['hora_inicio'],
                'hora_fim' => $row['hora_fim']
            );

            // Adicione um dia para próxima data
            $data = AddDia($data);
        }
    } else {
        // Outros tipos de evento
        $eventos[] = Array(
            'data_inicio' => $row['data_inicio'],
            'data_fim' => $row['data_fim'],
            'hora_inicio' => $row['hora_inicio'],
            'hora_fim' => $row['hora_fim']
        );
    }
}
```

Caso o usuário não deseje uma data final, coloque no código uma limitação de datas, exemplo:

```
$maxdata = AddDia(Date(), 2*365); // Data máxima 2 anos

foreach ($res as $row){
    $data_inicio = $row['data_inicio'];
    $data_fim = empty($row['data_fim']) ? $maxdata : $row['data_fim'];

    // Calcule o intervalo das datas em dias
    $intervalo == IntervaloDias($data_inicio, $data_fim);
```

Caso não queria os dias do fim de semana:

```
// Adicione um dia para próxima data
$data = AddDia($data);

if (date( "w", $data) == 6){ // Sábado
    $data = AddDia($data, 2); // Vai para segunda feira
}
```